# Thom Space of $S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The Thom space of the tangent bundle of $S^n$ by the Thom isomorphism has reduced cohomology $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimensions $n$ and $2n$. It is also the case that it suspends to $S^{2n+1} \vee S^{n+1}$ since adding a trivial bundle makes it trivial, and the Thom space of a trivial bundle is the repeated suspension of the space with a disjoint basepoint.

Is this just a stable equivalence or is it always true that the Thom space of the sphere is a wedge of spheres? Perhaps this can be reduced to a question about Hopf invariants?

Comment: The Thom space of $TS^2$ is the cofiber of the projection $SO_3\rightarrow S^2$. If I checked correctly this is $S^2\cup_{2\cdot\eta}e^4$.

Comment: @Tyrone I’ve checked this and it is indeed true. Though it does not seem open to generalization as it required calculating the cup product, and two cell complexes being classified by cup product is very unique to this dimension.

Comment: @Tyrone Do you think it might be the case that it is the cofiber of the Whitehead bracket of the identity with itself, in general? They coincide for $n=2$ and like the Whitehead bracket it vanishes after a suspension.

Comment: It's an interesting thought. Of course the cofiber of the Whitehead product on $S^n$ is the $2n$-skeleton of $\Omega S^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Tyrone Is it also true that the Thom space of $TS^2$ is $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$, as it is an $S^2$ bundle over $S^2$?

Comment: @Borromean $\mathbb{C}P^2\#\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ does not have the correct homology to support a Thom isomorphism, unless I have misunderstood what you intend.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks for the correction! I misunderstood the Thom space and I made a wrong comment.